# Issues with font/text-color in css

Tags: html, css

I keep having issues with the text-color rule in css whereas I'll have a code like this:

```
#horizontal > ul > li > a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(255,101,101);
    text-color: black;
```

And the background color will change, but the text remains blue.

Comment: you should use just color: black; text-color is not a css property

Answer (score 2):

The colour property in CSS is 'color' not 'text-color'.

Comment: Well I feel like a dunce now.. Haha. I could've sworn that text-color or at the very least font-color was a style rule in css.. It may only work in html though..

Answer (score 0):

Use `color: black;` "text-color" is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

Use `color`

```
#horizontal > ul > li > a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(255,101,101);
    color: black;
```